# How to retrieve Azure DevOps releases for a work-item using Azure DevOps cli

Tags: command-line-interface, azure-devops-extensions

In the Azure DevOps web interface, it is possible to check which releases are associated with a work item (see in the picture).

However, this information does not seem to be available through the Azure DevOps CLI.
I tried the following command:
`az boards work-item show --id 1234` to retrieve information related to work item with id `1234`.
I could not get the information related to the associated releases.
However, the returned information shows most of the elements on that page. For example:

- Reproduction steps -> `Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps`
- Severity -> `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity`
- Relations -> `relations`

Hence, I believe there's a way to retrieve information related to the releases.

[image]

**EDIT**

The following image is what I get when I run the below command. I get the **"Integrated in build"** relation but not the **"Integrated in release environment"** relation.

`az boards work-item show --id 1234 --query relations[].attributes.name`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part named "`Integrated in release environment`" in the response body is about the releases associated with the work item.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when I run the same command, I don't have "Integrated in release environment" relation.  Please take a look at the picture I added in the EDIT.

Comment: How about using [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0): `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/wit/workitems/{witId}?$expand=ALL&api-version=6.0`  ? [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx7SK.png)

Comment: Hi, I think I'm already using the expand=ALL property, since it shows the attributes array. My workaround for now is to indirectly get releases through different calls.

Comment: Can you share your workaround as an answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the workaround easily.